# Scrapping Annual Reports for Companies

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am extracting annual reports pdf file from the website .

```
import requests
import pandas as pd 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
url1 = "https://investor.alaskaair.com/financial-information/sec-filings?field_nir_sec_form_group_target_id%5B%5D=471&field_nir_sec_date_filed_value=#views-exposed-form-widget-sec-filings-table"
source = requests.get(url1)
soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text , "html.parser")
```

I am trying to extract columns from the above mentioned URL but in the view column we have only 8 rows thus throws value Error = arrays must all be same length

```
tag2 = soup.find_all('div' , class_="field field--name-field-nir-sec-form-group field--type-entity-reference field--label-inline field__item")
def filing_group(tag2):
    filing_group = []
    for i in tag2:
        filing_group.append(i.text.strip())
    return filing_group
filing_group(tag2) 

tag4 = soup.find_all('span' , class_ = "file file--mime-application-pdf file--application-pdf")
def view(tag4):
    view = []
    try: 
        for i in tag4:
            view.append(i.a.get('href'))
    except AttributeError:
        view.append(None)
    return view
view(tag4)

def scrape_page():
    all_info = {}
    all_info = {
        "Filing Group" : [],
        "View" : []
    }
    all_info["Filing Group"] += filing_group(tag2) 
    all_info["View"] += view(tag4)
    
    return all_info
scrape_page_df = pd.DataFrame(scrape_page())
```

Comment: I run the code without any errors.

Comment: sorry in order to reduce the length of code i wrote long lines. If you can please check again that would be of great help. Thanks

Comment: put `try/except` of `view` function inside the `for` loop. You have put `for` loop inside the `try`

Comment: It seems two rows does not have corresponding pdf files in the original link. So, the length of annual list (10) does not match pdf list (8). You need to know which ones are missing and then pad the missing ones with Na.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
table = soup.find('table', {'class':"nirtable views-table views-view-table cols-5 collapse-table-wide"})
trs = [x.find_all('td') for x in table.find_all('tr')]
vs = []
ls = []
for tr in trs:
    if len(tr)>0:
        v = 'https://investor.alaskaair.com/'+tr[1].a['href']
        print(v)
        try:
            l = tr[4].find('span', {'class':'file file--mime-application-pdf file--application-pdf'}).a.get('href')
        except:
            l = None
        print(l)
        vs.append(v)
        ls.append(l)
pd.DataFrame({'v':vs, 'l':ls})
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but when i am using this piece of code to fetch the FORM Column it throws error  TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: Just changed tr[3] to tr[1], and works perfectly.

Comment: If you change that too tr[1] the output is 10K but i am looking for its href which can directly take me to the website

Comment: The reason is that your original question was something else. Edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks man If you can share some source from where i can study more in depth .

Comment: You're welcome. Actually, I just replied from my experience and some shallow web search. If you have other questions, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @hteza, there are missing links so you need to build your data row by row and not column by column:

```
table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'views-table'})
data = []
for row in table.find('tbody').find_all('tr'):
    group = row.find('div', {'class': 'field field--name-field-nir-sec-form-group field--type-entity-reference field--label-inline field__item'}).text
    pdf = row.find('span', {'class': 'file file--mime-application-pdf file--application-pdf'})
    view = pdf.find('a')['href'] if pdf else None
    data.append({'Filling Group': group, 'View': view})

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    Filling Group                                                                              View
0  Annual Filings  https://investor.alaskaair.com/static-files/a686b1d8-6bc5-41ee-9e1a-3860907ed26f
1  Annual Filings  https://investor.alaskaair.com/static-files/33d26e56-06c0-44bc-8078-58fbd8103186
2  Annual Filings  https://investor.alaskaair.com/static-files/16b87b83-b3bf-4e33-8ef5-148cf48b336b
3  Annual Filings  https://investor.alaskaair.com/static-files/5e3082dd-f9fe-493e-9bf9-978c658a13a4
4  Annual Filings  https://investor.alaskaair.com/static-files/086708d7-3a13-4683-a381-21eb77634172
5  Annual Filings  https://investor.alaskaair.com/static-files/a09bc200-0c2b-478c-8827-d84044c1fcba
6  Annual Filings  https://investor.alaskaair.com/static-files/66234ad1-4934-4330-8770-36c4ccebebd0
7  Annual Filings                                                                              None
8  Annual Filings  https://investor.alaskaair.com/static-files/78aa7028-887b-41e8-a173-bf27dccb34b0
9  Annual Filings                                                                              None
```